# Database not copying from assets

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Little to say ill just paste my code hoping that someone will see what im missing:

**Database.Java**

```
package gr.peos;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/gr.peos/databases/";

//Name of the Database to be created.
private static String DB_NAME = "BLib";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

 /**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */

public Database(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    //First we check if the database already exists, Method declared later
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase(); 

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exists
    }else{

        //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are going to be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase(); //Method declared later

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
          }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */


private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}



/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transferring byte stream.
 * */

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}




//Opening the Database
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}


/
//Finally overriding a few methods as required

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

The part to call this is on the onCreate method of my main activity (Tried others too it wasnt the problem).

```
 Database myDbHelper = new Database(null);
    myDbHelper = new Database(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

try {



}catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

  }
```

The weird part now. On my device (I dont have root access so cant extract the db after it's been created), my Data appears to be 48KB. When running the exact same code on the emulator the database isnt copied over (Im not picking on any exception). To be exact the android/metadata table seems to be getting copied but the other tables along with the data arent. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your database's name?

Comment: The one in the assets folder? BLib

Comment: uninstall the app from emulator and rerun the code.

Comment: Done around a million times :P

Comment: any extension like as .sqlite or .db ..?

Comment: sql, think i've tried with sqlite3 aswell, do i have to include the extension in DB_NAME or remove the extension from the file before i place it in assets?

Comment: if your file name have extension in assets folder so must add it in code. see my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am giving you the complete code,plz reply if you success

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private Context mycontext;

private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/gr.peos/databases/";
//private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "BLib.sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
/*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                            + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                            + "/databases/";*/

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException  {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.mycontext=context;
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if(dbexist)
    {
        //System.out.println("Database exists");
        opendatabase(); 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    createdatabase();
    }

}

public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if(dbexist)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
    }
    else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
            copydatabase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkdatabase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkdb;
}
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/gr.peos/databases/BLib.sqlite");

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();

}

public void opendatabase() throws SQLException
{
    //Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}



public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDataBase != null){
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

Comment: It does copy some sort of a database now but trying to open it with the firefox extension after exporting it from DDMS i get: Database corrupt.

Comment: It worked was something i forgot to edit myself as i said. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I also had the same problem and for solving it,it took 1 week:) The error got solved by inserting this line "checkdb = dbfile.exists();
"

Comment: The line this.getReadableDatabase() makes my Nexus 7 to crash. Strangly it works on all my other devices.

Comment: will it be work on Android 2.2 devices/Emulator? because i got crash on that.

Comment: @JaydeepKhamar @CapDroid I experienced strange behavior. I have created DB using SQLite Browser.Created DB has not any extension. So I need to declare `DB_NAME = "DBNAME"` and at `myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/packagename/databases/DBNAME" + ".db");`. If I do like that then only I am able to copy the database. but then the other issue occurs in which two files are generated in databases folder. One is DBNAME and the other is DBNAME.db. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

if your file name have extension in assets folder to must add in code.

like

```
private static String DB_NAME = "BLib.extension";
```

extension is like as ".sqlite",".db"  ...etc

Comment: Both the answers actually helped me. My checkdb had a slight error and i also forgot to put the extension for the file. Thank you very much for the help <3

Comment: Will that code works in android 2.2 devicecs and Emulator also? I got crash on this code.