# get database from external source and populate listview

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I'm developing an application where lot of data is involved. It is not advisable to enter each and every database entry in `onCreate()` method. I found a software called SQLite database browser using which I can create the database with all my data filled.

My question is how do I link this db file in the program. 
I would be very glad if any one of you could provide me with a code snippet of the same.

Also, please give me a brief description of how the whole thing can be achieved. I have doubts and I'm not getting needed answers in any of the forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the modified database file in assets folder and then copy it into your application programmatically.
Refer my answer of this link 
[Database not copying from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945196/database-not-copying-from-assets/5945326#5945326)