# SqliteDatabase not found in DDMS

Tags: android, sql

I have been stuck on this for a while now and iv changed my code so many times it pains me.Anyway i have made a DB in sql database browser i have been reading on how to place it in my app that am working on at the moment.So i placed it in my assets folder and made a database helper java class.But i just can get my DB file into eclipse DDMS i have look at stack overflows answer but just don't know where the problem lies. I changed my DBHelper code again to [Database not copying from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945196/database-not-copying-from-assets/5945326#5945326) and still no DB file in my DDMS.

The image's you see are were i am at the moment.This is the first computer coding iv ever done
am new to android.Thank You

http://s1.postimg.org/6u667r3bj/snip1.jpg

http://s13.postimg.org/l5vsas40n/snip2.jpg

```
   package com.mybasicapp;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.SQLException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

   public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
   private Context mycontext;

  private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/gr.peos/databases/";
 //private String DB_PATH = 
 mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
 private static String DB_NAME = "BLib.sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
 public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
  /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";*/

  public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException  {
   super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
   this.mycontext=context;
   boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
   if(dbexist)
  {
    //System.out.println("Database exists");
    opendatabase(); 
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
   createdatabase();
  }

 }

  public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
   boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
   if(dbexist)
   {
    //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
   }
   else{
       this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        copydatabase();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
      }
    }
  }
  private boolean checkdatabase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
   boolean checkdb = false;
    try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    File dbfile = new File(myPath);
    //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    checkdb = dbfile.exists();
     }
     catch(SQLiteException e){
    System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

     return checkdb;
   }
  private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

   //Open your local db as the input stream
   InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

  // Path to the just created empty db
   String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

   //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/gr.peos/databases  
  /BLib.sqlite");

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
   while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
   {
    myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

     //Close the streams
     myoutput.flush();
     myoutput.close();
     myinput.close();

   }

   public void opendatabase() throws SQLException
  {
   //Open the database
  String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }



    public synchronized void close(){
  if(myDataBase != null){
    myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
    }

  @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   }
```

Comment: did you override onCreate() method in your DB class?

Comment: I dont really know what your saying about onCreate() in which java this above because am finding it hard to get my head round this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you wont to add a ready SQLite file to you db folder.

1. Open your emulator and make sure it's selected.
2. In the DDMS open /data/data/[your_package_name]/databases folder and select it.
3. Use the - + buttons to pull and insert the files.

[image]

Comment: Man i did this like ten time i did it again and pushed the file onto it thanks. Am not to sure where i go from here but i was stuck on a  tutorial thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the database and move it manually in the project. It will be automatically created if it doesn't exist. So there are 2 methods to override to create your database and change it if database version changes. Just call

```
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

in the constructor, where the "1" is your database version. If you change it to "2" and the database already exists "onUpgrade" will be called.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
```

will be automatically called if your database doesn't exist. In this you would like to add tables to it.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

will be automatically called if the database version on the device is below the given database version in the app. In this method you change tables if they has changed between the versions.

I would suggest to create a second class to interact your database (open/close/insert). Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLiteOpenHelper is the right way to go.  It works great for me.  However, the only functions I'm overriding are

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

I'm letting it create the database in its default location, in the root of my app's internal storage area, I think.

In your case, if I understand what you posted, you want to copy a database from the assets folder to internal storage.  My suggestion is 4 parts:

1. Temporarily let Android create an empty db for you and figure out where it put it.
2. Modify your copyDatabase code to copy to that location.
3. Override onCreate to call copyDatabase.  Android will only call onCreate if no database exists, thus you can unconditionally call copyDatabase.
4. In the future, as you make schema changes, handle them in onUpgrade.

That should be all.  Let me know how you progress with this.

One caveat: onCreate already creates an empty database, so I'm not sure copying a db from assets will work without somehow closing and reopening the db.  Another approach, which I'm using is to put DDL in your assets file instead and process that in onCreate.  Something like this (except I'm using an array of strings instead of an asset file):

```
String[] ddl = 
{
  "CREATE TABLE [T1] ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL, [col1] CHAR);" +
  "CREATE TABLE [T2] ([id] INTEGER NOT NULL, [col2] CHAR)";
};

db.beginTransaction();
try
{
  for (int i = 0, limit = ddl.length;  i < limit;  i++)
    db.execSQL (ddl [i]);
} finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```