# Android copy SQLite database from asset not work on KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I red different question here on StackOverflow but mine is a little bit newer.

All of these don't work:
[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501133/android-copy-sqlite-database-from-asset-issue-i-got-a-database-without-any-tab)
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805874/copy-database-from-assets-to-databases-folder)
[Question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354154/copy-sqlite-database-from-assets-folder)

I updated my devices to Android KitKat 4.4 and when I try to copy database with this code:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

I obtain a FileNotFoundException at line:

```
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
```

Someone fix this issue on Android KitKat??? (other platforms works great)

Thanks for help.

Giulio

Comment: show your  DB_PATH + DB_NAME string

Comment: Is DB_PATH fully hardcoded or do you get the root directory for it via the Environment class?

Comment: Full hardcoded: DB_PATH = /data/data/it.test.testsqlite/databases/ DB_NAME = test.sqlite

Answer (score 4):

> Full hardcoded

**NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. [Use `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to find the proper place for a database.

> other platforms works great

It certainly will crash on Android 4.2+ tablets for secondary accounts. It may crash in other environments as well. **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**.

Note that [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) uses `getDatabasePath()`.

Comment: It's a really strange behavior. I installed app and at first launch it crashes with FileNotFoundException. Then I terminate app, relaunch and all works. I'm not crazy! Anyway thanks for advice, I will replace getDatabasePath() instead hardcoded path. Thanks! :)

Comment: @GiulioBider: It is possible that you need to create the directory yourself; I do not see where you are doing that in your code.

Comment: Replaced getDatabasePath() instead of hardcoding path. I use code above inside constructor of SQLiteHelper subclass. First launch doesn't work, if I terminate app and relaunch all works great.

Comment: hi commonsware! your answer solved my query too! but when i obfuscate the build i get same issue! does Obfuscation has to do something with the issue